# Correct syntax to remove list elements by value from MySQL array

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL array converted to a Python list and I want to remove an element by value from the list. This is what I've tried:

```
existingEpisodeIDs = list(c.fetchall())
existingEpisodeIDs = [(22528819L,), (22604873L,), (22677186L,)]
id = 22528819
listElement = '(' + str(id) + 'L,)'
existingEpisodeIDs.remove(listElement)
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Given the above data, can anyone advise me about the correct syntax to use for removing an element, or suggest a better way to achieve the desired result?

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't you use quotes for existingEpisodeIDs elements?

Comment: L is not a string. by typing existingEpisodeIDs.remove((id,)) you get your desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
existingEpisodeIDs = [row[0] for row in c.fetchall()] #this will end up just being a list of id's
id = 22528819
existingEpisodeIDs.remove(id)
```

Comment: "list comprehensions" - I knew there was a better way, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
In [17]: existingEpisodeIDs = [(22528819L,), (22604873L,), (22677186L,)]

In [18]: id = 22528819

In [19]: existingEpisodeIDs.remove((id,)) #tuple with the id

In [20]: existingEpisodeIDs
Out[20]: [(22604873L,), (22677186L,)]
```

just a quick reply about your mistake here: the L identifies a long-type

```
In [23]: type(existingEpisodeIDs[0][0])
Out[23]: long
```

there is no need for you to construct a string with the L at the end, you just construct the tuple with your id that needs to be removed and you're set :)